# Which preposition should be used with word 'Natural'

Tags: prepositions

> 1.It is natural **to** me to help her.
>   2.It is natural **for** me to help her.

Comment: It depends on the verb that’s used with it. It is natural for me and it seems natural to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say that it is natural for someone to act in a particular way or for something to happen in that way, you mean that it is reasonable in the circumstances. (Collins Dictionary)

That’s why “it’s natural for me to help her” is correct.

You can also say, “It’s in my nature to help her.”